# FragmentActivity and Toast.makeText

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

My **MainActivity** extends **FragmentActivity**. I have a **Toast.makeText** in **onCreate** method in button's **SetonClickListener**. Toast is not showing up. I used **getApplicationContext()**, **MainActivity.this**,**getApplication()**. All fails. I tried turning on the app notifications of this particular app on my device but no success.

**EDIT**

I forgot To use show() method. Thanks to shobhit

Comment: Can you please post the code sniplet yo show how are you calling it ? Can you just try `MainActivity.this` and remove the `getApplication()` ? Also make sure you are calling `.show()` on it. So something like: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27040452/2413303

Comment: Thanks Shobhit,I forgot to use show() method.

Answer (score 0):

Probabaly you don't call the `show()` method.

and try to use getActivity() instead of `MainActivity.this`